# Pyspark UDF evaluation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

So I have a simple function which takes in two strings and converts them into float(consider it is always possible) and returns the max of them.

```
def val_estimate(amount_1: str, amount_2: str) -> float:

   return max(float(amount_1), float(amount_2))
```

When I evaluate the function on the following arguments, I get the output as expected:

```
val_estimate("2000000","90125900")

Output: 
90125900.0
```

Now, when I register the function above as a UDF and use it on a spark dataframe with same arguments, I get the following results.

```
val_estimate_udf = F.udf(val_estimate, returnType = FloatType())

df = spark.createDataFrame( [["2000000","90125900"]], ['sale_amt', 'total_value'])

df = df.withColumn("check",val_estimate_udf(F.col("sale_amt"),F.col("total_value")))
display(df)
```

Output:

| sale_amt | total_value | check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000 | 90125900 | 90125904 |

Why am I getting this result? Please ignore lack of error handling, etc. and the fact that I can use native spark function to do the same, but I can't understand this result.

Comment: Maybe not understanding this, but to me the result is as expected, the check column returns as a float the value 90125904?

Comment: Yes, the check column returns as 90125904 instead of 91025900.

Comment: apologies I missed the slight 4 difference. I could recreate your issue. Looks like some floating point rounding issue. Try changing the return type to a `DoubleType()` e.g. `@udf(returnType = DoubleType())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import  DoubleType

@udf(returnType = DoubleType()) 
def val_estimate(amount_1: str, amount_2: str) -> float:
   return max(float(amount_1), float(amount_2))
  
df = spark.createDataFrame( [('2000000', '90125900')], ['sale_amt', 'total_value'])
df2 = df.withColumn("check", val_estimate(F.col("sale_amt"), F.col("total_value")))
df2.show()
```

Comment: Is this due to overflow in float type?

Comment: Honestly, I'm unsure, but good guess :) I just know from experience on various other languages that float precision can be a problem. You may want to raise as an issue with the Spark development team https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues/SPARK-34827?filter=allopenissues

Comment: Thanks, it works. Seems to be an overflow issue.